# remove margin between QLabel and QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm trying to create Login Window, which has QLineEdit below QLabel, but the current QLabel taking too many space in Window, i don't know why, here is the picture :

```
QLabel { background-color: red; }
```

[image: red]

My Code :

```
self.text = QLabel("LOGIN")

# self.text.setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color: red; color : white;margin-top: 50px;margin-bottom: 0px; }")
self.text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
# self.text.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
# self.text.setGeometry(QRect(10,10,30,80))

font = QFont("Sans-Serif", 30)
self.text.setFont(font)

form = QLineEdit("Write my name here..")
form.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
# form.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)

self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
# self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
self.layout.setSpacing(0)
self.layout.addWidget(self.text)
self.layout.addWidget(form)
self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

[image]

Comment: You could place an image or scheme of what you want to get

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm trying to make this window https://www.fbvpn.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Windows-installation-enter-username-password.png

Comment: In the image you provide shows 3 windows, which of the 3 windows do you want your window to look like?

Comment: @eyllanesc the LOGIN Window

Comment: In the login window it has the following structure: an image, then the text "LOG IN", then 2 inputs, 1 button and one more text. I do not see that this is the structure that you try in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see the relationship between the code provided by the OP and the LOGIN window from which you want to copy the structure, so create the following code from scratch.

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class LoginPage(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.login_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            text=self.tr("LOG IN"), alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
        )
        self.email_username_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(
            placeholderText=self.tr("Email or username")
        )
        self.password_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(
            placeholderText=self.tr("Password"), echoMode=QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password
        )
        self.enter_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("Enter"))
        self.forgot_password_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            self.tr("Forgot password?"), alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
        )

        self.image_label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("so-icon.png"))

        # font = self.
        font = self.login_label.font()
        font.setPointSize(30)
        self.login_label.setFont(font)

        self.login_label.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )
        self.forgot_password_label.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.addWidget(self.image_label)
        lay.addWidget(self.login_label)
        lay.addWidget(self.email_username_lineedit)
        lay.addWidget(self.password_lineedit)
        lay.addWidget(self.enter_button)
        lay.addWidget(self.forgot_password_label)

        self.resize(320, 480)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = LoginPage()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]